# Python Flask Request None Problem on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have this piece of code it is a post method (Python Flask),

````
@application.route('/try', methods=['POST'])
def tryPost() :
    content = "```" + str(request.json) + "```"
    return jsonify(content)
````

When i run the app locally and post json on postman to the http://127.0.0.1:5000/try , i can see the same json result.

But after i push my app to the aws elastic beanstalk, and i posted the same method it returned ```` "```None```" ````

What would be the reason?

This the example json

```
{
    "api_app_id": "A02",
    "token": "Shh_its_a_seekrit",
    "container": {
        "type": "message",
        "text": "The contents of the original message where the action originated"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.json` only works when you send a request with `Content-Type` of `application/json`. Otherwise is `None`.

Without the content-type, you should use `request.data`:

````
@application.route('/try', methods=['POST'])
def tryPost() :
    content = "```" + str(request.data) + "```"
    return content
````

Comment: Thank you @Marcin, but now it returns like this, how can i fix this? ;  b'{\r\n\t"api_app_id": "A02",\r\n\t"token": "Shh_its_a_seekrit",\r\n\t"container": {\r\n\t\t"type": "message",\r\n\t\t"text": "The contents of the original message where the action originated"\r\n\t}\r\n}'

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman I think you have to just return `request.data`, without `str` operation.

Comment: but then i cannot concatenate with other strings :/

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman Sorry, I don't know what do you want to achieve. Why not pass Content-Type of application/json with your request?

Comment: Thank you @Marcin, i wanted to show this requests on slack. I returned that str(request.data, "utf-8") and it works.